# iOS access to logs after sync

Tags: iphone, ios, logging

I have search and not really finding an answer.

What kinda of log access does the iOS SDK offer after you have finished syncing with iTunes but are still connected to your computer?

Can my App access any data in the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any application can access the ASL logs in iOS using the API. ASL is Apple's version of syslogd btw. Type `man 3 asl` or read the [Peter Hosey series on ASL](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2008-01-19/next-week-apple-system-logger).

[AppSwitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appswitch/id398317469) is a commercial application that does just that. The sync process logs are a bit boring though, there is no detailed recollection of files synced, just the process itself... connected to usb, starting backup, blah blah.

**edit:** If something interesting appears on your computer during sync, you should be able to see it running [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) You'll see activity on syncservices.log, crash reports logs if any, and other files.

Comment: AppSwitch is nice for looking over the device itself but I'm looking more for Logs on your Mac/Win machine after you can synced your iPhone. I need to still look over the ASL link you provided